# Ansible DC/OS deployment

Tags: mesos, dcos

I've just written an Ansible playbook that deploys DC/OS with their CloudFormation template as shown here:
https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/administration/installing/cloud/aws/
And it works fine!

Now I'm trying to connect on DC/OS with Ansible to deploy stuff on it, but of course I need to login first.
The way I know to create the first account is to visit with a browser the DC/OS page.

But I want to create this first account programmatically for Ansible, how can I do so?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Source DC/OS currently uses dcos-oauth

The easiest way to automatically create a user is to create the relevant ZNode in ZooKeeper (/dcos/users/). Hopefully Ansible has a plugin to do this.

Relevant code here:

https://github.com/dcos/dcos-oauth/blob/master/dcos-oauth/login.go#L100

This being said, we're planning to open source parts of our Identity and Access Management service in the 1.10 release (available towards the end of 2016 or early 2017), at which point open DC/OS will get a REST API to do this automation.

Comment: That sounds like a solution for creating a user, but then I will need to find a way to get the token to configure the command line tool in order to deploy apps.
Is there a solution for that too?

Comment: You can obtain an authentication token by logging in with the CLI and running:

dcos config show core.dcos_acs_token

Note that this token expires after 5 days, which is probably fine for use in scripts you run yourself, but less than ideal for a CI/CD setup since it still requires some manual intervention on your part.

We plan on addressing this in the 1.10 time frame by adding service accounts to Open DC/OS.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answers @fullung.
As a user feedback note: I think for us this is a blocker for using DC/OS as we want to be able to up and down the whole environment in one command, plus we are deploying from Jenkins automatically and therefore we don't want to refresh the key manually every 5 days. I think we will be awaiting DCOS 1.10 with impatience.